# Visual Studio Custom Tools list

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-2010

Where can I find Visual Studio's available custom tools list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, accidentally, I ended up looking in the Registry, where I found what I wanted at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Generators\` subkeys.
For sure, it would be similar in older VS versions.

Comment: In my case, I had to look under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Generators

Comment: I had to look under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Generators\ ` because I was on a 64 bit system. The Wow6432Node is where 32 bit programs save their settings on a 64 bit system.